# Sharing a library between two sites, without designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-library

Does anyone know how to create a Web Part to show a specific View of a Library from another SharePoint site? I am not allowed to download Designer but need to show another Site's Library! They have a group of documents that we share so it would be much easier to upload once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Content Query Web Part.

Then choose the site and library you want to display.

Comment: I basically only have full control (end user) permissions and cannot activate this web part. Is there another way?

Comment: If you have full control then you can go to site settings and activate feature. This is the SharePoint recommended method. Otherwise you need to use JavaScript etc. which has its own downfall.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Html Form Web Part.

- Add a HTML Form Web Part to the page you wish to display the list, or
  document library on.
- Edit the webpart and click on "Source Editor". Delete the default
  code, and add the following:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
>
> <!-- Load and display list - jQuery version -->
> <!-- Questions and comments: 
>
> Christophe@PathToSharePoint.com -->
> <DIV id="ListPlaceholder"><IMG src="/_layouts/images/GEARS_AN.GIF"></DIV>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
> // Paste the URL of the source list below:
> var 
>
> SelectedView = "http://domain.com/path-to-site/Lists/list-name/view-name.aspx";
> $("#ListPlaceholder").load(SelectedView+" #WebPartWPQ2 .ms-listviewtable",function() {
> $("#ListPlaceholder 
>
> *").removeAttr("id");
> //$("#ListPlaceholder *").removeAttr("onclick");
> //$("#ListPlaceholder *").removeAttr("onfocus");
> //$("#ListPlaceholder *").removeAttr("onmouseover");
> });
> </script>
> ```

- Click OK, then save the page. The list didn't display until I saved
  the page.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/4d7fceb8-9832-442a-b27f-334a680a01aa/display-a-document-library-on-a-different-site-collection

Comment: I keep getting a "cannot save your changes" error. I'm not good at coding and have no idea why I was put in charge of this lol. when I paste the code in, how do I put the url into it?

Comment: in the code SelectedView = "http://domain.com/path-to-site/Lists/list-name/view-name.aspx"  ...replace the url wit your deisred url.

Comment: I tried that and I still get a "cannot retrieve properties at this time" and a "cannot save changes" error. -_-

Comment: Update: I got rid of the error box but the only thing that shows is a green loading circle....