# How do I share a LIST within a site collection WITHOUT using SP Designer?? Using SharePoint 2013

Tags: html-form-web-part

I found this older question and answer on this exchange that pertains to my situation.  However, the answers are incomplete.
[Sharing a library between two sites, without designer?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142240/sharing-a-library-between-two-sites-without-designer/142250#142250)

However, I followed the directions and got the HTML Web Part to show a green circle loading.  The person asking the question before me had the same problem.  However, no one answered.

I did try using the Content Query web part.  However, it only showed one column of the list.  (I have a simple POC list with name, title, email, and phone number)  The Content Query web part only shows the names found under one of the columns in the list I want.

I have full admin control.  I do not do coding and we are not allowed to use SP Designer in my organization....not that I would know how to properly use it if I did have access to it...I can follow simple coding steps such as the above link.

Thank-you,
Helen

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: sorry - SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `SharePoint Designer` and `Content Query web part`, you can't **simply** achieve your goal! and you will need to write a custom code that I think it is the hardest option especially most of JSOM/JS samples over the internet is not working to show the list view with its traditional structure properly!

So to code that you need to get the list items and show it in Gridview using SSOM as an option! check this [Bind SharePoint List Items in a Gridview](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/746cd9/bind-sharepoint-list-items-in-a-gridview/)

So I suggest asking the decision maker to at least allow you to install and use SPD from your machine and follow the steps that mentioned at

- [Display a SharePoint List from Parent Site in Sub Site](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/11/06/show-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site-sharepoint-2016/)
- [SP 2016 - Display list from Parent site in sub-site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226651/sp-2016-display-list-from-parent-site-in-sub-site/226657)

Comment: Would the steps involving SPD be fairly comprehensive and easy to follow.  I do not do coding.  I can ask my client but want to feel fairly confident that I can accomplish what I need without "hurting" the site.

Comment: Yes, you can follow up the steps without hurting the site,